# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for self "required to be static"

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am prototyping channel based system and when converting code to use async tasks, I came across the error that `&mut self` needs to have an appropriate lifetime.

I have tried setting the `&mut self` to `&'static self` but that does not work. I have tried to wrap the entire code in an async block returning `Future<Output=()> + 'static` which also did not work.

Here is the code:

```rust
struct RequestManager {
    connection_state: ConnectionState,
    backoff: u64,
    exponent: u32,
    maximum: u64,
}

impl RequestManager {
    async fn run(&mut self, mut feed_queue: Receiver<FeedItem>) {
        let (mut fetch_result_sender, mut fetch_result_receiver) = channel(5);
        let (mut fetch_request_sender, mut fetch_request_receiver) = channel::<FeedItem>(5);

        let request_sender = mpsc::Sender::clone(&fetch_result_sender);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                match self.connection_state {
                    ConnectionState::Closed => {
                        while let Some(feed) = fetch_request_receiver.recv().await {
                            let mut request_sender = mpsc::Sender::clone(&request_sender);
                            tokio::spawn(async move {
                                let response = make_request(&feed.feed_address).await;
                                if let Err(_) = response {
                                    self.connection_state =
                                        ConnectionState::HalfOpen(feed.feed_address);
                                } else {
                                    let response = read_response_body(response.unwrap()).await;
                                    let result = FetchResult { body: response };
                                    if let Err(e) = request_sender.send(result).await {
                                        eprintln!("could not send fetch result: {}", e);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    ConnectionState::HalfOpen(url) => {
                        let response = make_request(&url).await;
                        if let Err(_) = response {
                            self.connection_state = ConnectionState::Open(url);
                        } else {
                            let response = read_response_body(response.unwrap()).await;
                            let result = FetchResult { body: response };
                            // // TODO: sends to task/feedService
                            connection_state = ConnectionState::Closed;
                            if let Err(e) = fetch_result_sender.send(result).await {
                                eprintln!("could not send fetch result: {}", e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ConnectionState::Open(url) => {
                        let new_backoff = calculate_backoff();
                        delay_for(Duration::from_secs(new_backoff));
                        self.connection_state = ConnectionState::HalfOpen(url)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What other code/libraries are you using? (for `ConnectionState`, `make_request`, `read_response_body`, etc.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]. It's usually best to reproduce the problem on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/), but if you cannot, then in a new Cargo project, and share all the files we need to reproduce the issue. Try to cut it down as much as possible, to avoid getting sidetracked -- if you can replace the whole body of a function with `todo!()`, hardcode function parameters, etc. then it will help us answer your question.

Comment: Also, please include in the question the exact compiler error you got, don't just tell us what you remember of it.